# Unable to start Web Sphere 7.0.0 Server

Tags: websphere, was7

I stopped Web Sphere 7.0.0 server using firststep.bat path (...\profiles\AppSrv01\firststeps).Now when I am trying to start I am getting follwing error

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\startServer.log
ADMU7701I: Because server1 is registered to run as a Windows Service, the
           request to start this server will be completed by starting the
           associated Windows Service.
ADMU7704E: Failed while trying to start the Windows Service associated with
           server: server1; 
probable error executing WASService.exe: Starting
           Service: AC001VMDDSK1244Node01
Timed out waiting for
           [start|stop]Server to complete, after 20 minutes. Failed to start
           service, or timed out while waiting for start to complete. Check the
           logs for details.
```

Comment: Please check SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log and provide more detail.

Comment: @fuero I found this in log "[23/05/13 06:30:54:933 BST] 00000003 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "server.startup : 2" (0000000b) has been active for 712049 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 3 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung." But I have already killed all the running process,Still unable to start

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the WAS Windows service is crashed. My suggestion is that remove and recreate the service with using **WASService.exe**.
You can find the steps on this link:
 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21397335